# What is the first verified twin study?

Tags: medicine

Today I learned that Swedish king Gustav III supposedly took two twin brothers that had been convicted for murder and had them [drink three pots of coffee and tea respectively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_III_of_Sweden%27s_coffee_experiment) per day. He supposedly did this to prove that coffee was bad for you, but ironically he got assassinated before either of the brother died.

However, there seems to be no contemporary records of this twin study so we don't know if it really happened. But that leads me to the question: **What was the first documented twin study?**

Wikipedia references [one in 1905](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_study), but that seems to be more about studying twins, than doing the type of twin study where you use twins to look for environmental factors, which is what Gustav III did.

Comment: Reading that makes me glad I'm not a twin. :P

Comment: Why not glad to not be a convicted murderer, which seems more pertinent.

Comment: @AmericanLuke - read about what [Dr. Josef Mengele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Mengele#Human_experimentation) did with twins, and you will be even gladder: "At Auschwitz, Mengele did a number of studies on twins. After an experiment was over, the twins were usually killed and their bodies dissected..."

Comment: "but ironically he got assassinated before either of the brother died" - too bad not many people in Sweden of the time read [Hodja Nasreddin parables](http://www.gnrtr.com/Generator.html?pi=150&cp=3) :)

Answer (score 4):

Hippocrates was fascinated by twins, but the concept and understanding of scientific research was different then from now.

In [this](http://books.google.ca/books?id=SADko_p6OlIC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=twins%20and%20hippocrates&source=bl&ots=mZGMKfweO0&sig=81CL8odNAuROQDTdQUBv_-H_mA0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Wgs_Uqj_EsWZqgG5r4HQAg&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=twins%20and%20hippocrates&f=false) work, St. Augustine writes on Cicero's commentary to Hippocrates' observations and speculations regarding one particular pair of brothers, who might have been twins. When the very question is that old, I believe attempts to identify the **first** such is doomed to be mired in speculation, personal opinion, and the *political correctness* of assigning it to this culture or that.

For the sake of completeness, [here](http://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Galton/twins.htm) is an 1875 study by Francis Galton.

Comment: Lennart is look for the first **verified** study. Doesn't that circumvent your problem with tracking down "the first"?

Comment: Unfortunately the 1875 study is also about studying twins, not using twins for studying something else. That prevents me from selecting this answer.